# How do you make a reverse triangle with stars in Java?

Tags: loops

So, I need to use a nested for loop in order to create a backwards triangle of stars, with 4 stars at the top, then the next line with only 3 stars, but with a space at the beginning, so each row ends up at the same column. It's a bit hard to describe, but the structure is in the comments in my code.

I can make a triangle that starts with 4 stars and ends with one star at the bottom, but I can't seem to make the spaces line up so that they all end at the same point. The closest I've gotten is the first two rows working, but the last two, with two and one stars respectively, don't.

Here's my code:

```
public static void stars()
//****
// ***
//  **
//   *
{
  int c = 0;
  for (int r = 4; r >= 1; r--)
    {
        for (c = r; c >= 1; c--)
        {

            System.out.print("*");
        }
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

If you have any responses, I welcome them.

Comment: In what way does this "not work"?  What output do you get?  When you debug, how does it differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another loop to print the spaces. The number of spaces for line `r` will simply be equal to `4 - r`:

```
public static void stars() {

    for (int r = 4; r >= 1; r--) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4 - r; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int c = r; c >= 1; c--){

            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
****
 ***
  **
   *
```